# Java SignalR client

Tags: java, c#, signalr

I'm trying to make `SignalR`'s [Java client](https://github.com/SignalR/java-client) Chat [example](https://github.com/SignalR/java-samples/tree/master/signalr-sample-chat) work properly, but adding new functionality to the java client side came to a full stop since the `closed` callback is never called once I turn the [server off](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr). I get the `connectionSlow` event, then the `stateChanged` is fired and lastly the `reconnecting` event. Even after 30 minutes the event is not fired.

Once I connect to the server, I get the following parameters:
KeepAliveTimeout: 20.0
DisconnectTimeout: 30.0

The documentation [clearly states](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#serverdisconnect) that after a certain period of time, the event should be fired.